# What are maximum theoretical network metrics for UDP packets?

Tags: performance, networking, network-programming, performance-testing, benchmarking

The goal is to determine metrics of an UDP protocol performance, specifically:

- Minimal possible **Theoretical** RTT (round-trip time, ping)
- Maximal possible **Theoretical** PPS of 1-byte-sized UDP Packets
- Maximal possible **Theoretical** PPS of 64-byte-sized UDP Packets
- Maximal and minimal possible theoretical jitter

This could and should be done without taking in account any slow software-caused issues(like 99% cpu usage by side process, inefficiently-written test program), or hardware (like busy channel, extremely long line, so on)

How should I go with **estimating** these best-possible parameters on a "real system"?

---

PS. I would offer a prototype, of what I call "a real system".

Consider 2 PCs, PC1 and PC2. They both are equipped with:

- modern fast processors(read "some average typical socket-1151 i7 CPU"), so processing speed and single-coreness are not an issues.
- some typical DDR4 @2400mhz..
- average NICs (read typical Realteks/Intels/Atheroses, typically embedded in mobos), so there is no very special complicated circuitry.
- a couple meters of ethernet 8 pair cable that connects their NICs, having established GBIT connection. So no internet, no traffic between them, other that generated by you.
- no monitors
- no any other I/O devices
- single USB flash per PC, that booted their initramfs to the RAM, and used to mount and store program output after test program finishes
- lightest possible software stack - There is probably busy box, running on top of latest Linux kernel, all libs are up-to-date. So virtually no software(read "busyware") runs on them.

And you run a server test program on PC1, and a client - on PC2. After program runs, USB stick is mounted and results are dumped to file, and system powers down then. So, I've described some ideal situation. I can't imagine more "sterile" conditions for such an experiment..

Comment: I suppose you're assuming that both systems are idle other than running your network test program, otherwise process scheduling could be a major variable.  Especially if other processes caused enough memory pressure that code pages for the test program were evicted from memory, resulting in hard page faults before user-space code could run.  (Especially if the program was running from the USB storage directly, instead of a ramdisk; or if tmpfs could page it out to swap space.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Hello. Nope, as i said, USB stick is only a source, used to decompress initramfs to ram, then it unmounts usb drive at all.. then lets throw out even busybox.. There are 2 processes, running. `init` and `test_program` that is launched via init script..

Comment: @PeterCordes that's the only point of separation, you cannot embed your code in a kernel, just can run as a part of some process in a user space.. but that's theory, i am about how these numbers are building?..

Comment: Are packets coming in fast enough to keep the CPU from going into a deep sleep?  That could add a few microseconds to the response time.  Also, a kernel with Meltdown + Spectre mitigation has higher system call overhead for the CPU entering/exiting the kernel.

Comment: @PeterCordes we can disable C31337 states in the bios. I saw it, but never bothered what is that for. I thought its some marketing stuff for "homeUsers", not useful for people who runs their 99.99% code 24/7 :)

Comment: I don't know if there's a useful way to predict packet response-time from pure theory.  Probably you'd need to find basically a benchmark of this to get some numbers to build from.  If you can rule out potential huge delays from non-realtime process scheduling or page faults, then the delays are a combination of lots of hardware factors that are probably very complicated to add, because some latencies might overlap with each other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195719/discussion-between-xakepp35-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: C states for saving power are almost always a good thing.  But if you have hard realtime requirements on worst-case latency that are much shorter than what humans can notice for interactive use, it's worth thinking about.  In real life you should let your desktop CPU sleep, but this question isn't about real life.  Although actually you're asking about *best*-case RTT, so we might as well assume fully warmed up and running at max turbo, with everything hot in cache.  Except for the maximal jitter part, then you need to think of worst-case assumptions which are *very* different.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's not for human-use, that's estimation attempt, for robotics use. It's not desktop PCs, thought they may use so-called desktop-PC hardware.. So yes, "being realtimish as hard as possible" - is good here. nice term, huh?)) So consider that you may use UDP packets as your only hard-RT transport.. and only 1 gbit networking restriction. No 2.5G, 5G, or 10Gbit.. what are the constraints, then?

Comment: It depends on your drivers.  e.g. https://www.evanjones.ca/ethernet-latency.html shows that typical RTT latency can be as bad as 125us if your e1000 drivers use interrupt coalescing.  (The onboard NIC on my Z170 mobo uses the e1000e driver; cheaper mobos often use Realtek instead of Intel, but Intel NICs are fairly sophisticated).  Benchmarks with a 1-byte TCP packet are relevant for your UDP case because the lower levels (IP packet / ethernet frame, and physical layer) are all the same, and the software layers are pretty similar.

Comment: [What is the minimum gigabit Ethernet latency I can expect?](//serverfault.com/q/874143) looks pretty relevant to your question with some ballpark numbers for various factors, including the NIC encoding/decoding bits onto the wire.  Google on `gigabit ethernet round trip time` for more.

Comment: "I do feel, like RTT time is order of hundreds microseconds" This is true for 
 dedicated hardware(actually is in the tens of microseconds) like ASICs, FPGAs or dedicated silicon; for general purpose CPU's running an OS, the 10s of milliseconds becomes close to 1 ms.

Comment: The lightest software stack is not Linux, but an RTOS which provides guarantees to execution order and timing. Which could get the RTT timing to "Hundreds of microseconds", or less, and still offers a reduced Jitter (still bounded by processor optimizations, but to a lesser extent)

Comment: @Strom 10us means 10khz, that even overexceends needs in 1khz. could you VTC this? I want no one ever see this info! Lets close it ASAP, i've copied your info and got my results! Lets close harted question, 4 votes are up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the PPS calculations take the total size of the frames and divide it into the Throughput of the medium.

**For IPv4**:

Ethernet Preamble and start of frame and the interframe gap 7 + 1 + 12 = 20 bytes.(not counted in the 64 byte minimum frame size)

Ethernet II Header and FCS(CRC) 14 + 4 = 18 bytes.
IP Header 20 bytes.
UDP Header 8 bytes.

Total overhead 46 bytes(padded to min 64 if payload is less than ) + 20 bytes "more on the wire"

Payload(Data)

1 byte payload -  becomes 18 based on 64 byte minimum + wire overhead. Totaling 84 bytes on the wire.

64 byte - 48 + 64 = 112 + 20 for the wire overhead = 132 bytes.

If the throughput of the medium is 125000000 bytes per second(1 Gb/s).

1-18 bytes of payload = 1.25e8 / 84 = max theoretical 1,488,095 PPS.

64 bytes payload = 1.25e8 / 132 = max theoretical 946,969 PPS.

These calculations assume a constant stream: The network send buffers are filled constantly. This is not an issue given your modern hardware description. If this were 40/100 Gig Ethernet CPU, bus speeds and memory would all be factors.

**Ping RTT time:**

To calculate the time it takes to transfer data through a medium divide the data transferred by the speed of the medium.

This is harder since the ping data payload could be any size 64 - MTU(~1500 bytes). ping typically uses the min frame size (64 bytes total frame size + 20 bytes wire overhead * 2 = 168 bytes) Network time(0.001344 ms) + Process response and reply time combined estimated between 0.35 and 0.9 ms. This value depends on too many internal CPU and OS factors, L1-3 caching, branch predictions, ring transitions (0 to 3 and 3 to 0) required, TCP/IP stack implemented, CRC calculations, interrupts processed, network card drivers, DMA, validation of data(skipped by most implementations)...

Max time should be < 1.25 ms based on anecdotal evidence.(My best eval was 0.6ms on older hardware(I would expect a consistent average of 0.7 ms or less on the hardware as described)).

**Jitter:**
The only inherent theoretical reason for *network* jitter is the asynchronous nature of transport which is resolved by the preamble. Max < (8 bytes)0.000512 ms. If sync is not established in this time the entire frame is lost. This is possibility that needs to be taken into account. Since UDP is best effort delivery.

As evidenced by the description of RTT: The possible variances in the CPU time in executing of identical code, as well as OS scheduling, and drivers makes this impossible to evaluate effectively.

If I had to estimate, I would design for a maximum of 1 ms jitter, with provisions for lost packets. It would be unwise to design a system intolerant of faults. Even for a "Perfect Scenario" as described faults **will** occur (a nearby lightening strike induces spurious voltages on the wire).  UDP has no inherent method for tolerating lost packets.

Comment: I think the OP didn't literally mean ICMP echo request, but rather round-trip to user-space on the other PC with a UDP packet (like the rest of the question is about).  They only use "ping" to loosely describe this, not because they're talking about the kernel sending an ICMP echo reply.

Comment: @PeterCordes, That is why my post did not include the specifics of the ICMP packet header details to describe the RTT as it is the same metrics as the minimum 64 byte packet.

Comment: I must have been still thinking of another answer I read just before this, on [What is the minimum gigabit Ethernet latency I can expect?](//serverfault.com/q/874143), which pointed out that ICMP echo-request handling might not be as optimized as normal paths for UDP / TCP.  You didn't say that but somehow I thought you did.

Comment: I love you/too drunk to google my ideas by myself on friday evening)) GJ, seems nice, we need 1khz hard-RT interaction over popular L4 OSI(UDP).. Glad it is sleeping for now.  :^) At first glance that robotic's joyful, but later on you would run into.. oh, just try it)) And never ever forget your calculations @home, humanity and services are on the desk!

Comment: @PeterCordes, That question came up in my research as well.  The measurement metrics given in that post are questionably sourced(i.e. not comparable to known ping times, Apples and Oranges).  The paths taken (as selected by the routing protocol, BGP, even if altered by congestion conditions) would be the same no matter the upper layer protocols.

Comment: @xakepp35, Maybe tomorrow you can translate that comment into English.  Until then have fun and enjoy your night.

Comment: @Strom The op didnt mean ICMP, he meant UDP, software-defined.. he is too drunk and is too "not allowed to disclosure". But this is the task, im the header - you must know your limits and test that UDP on 1.2.3.... that 123's also mentioned in header. What is the problem? You want to say, but dont know where exactly does YOUR WILL To HELP ENDS UP? (oh god that's most precie translation i've managed!)Go to girls then! Pick some some Stack Overflow Friday's Night Party! Probably there is no drink/beverage/booze at all..   As a programmer, I've picked quality cognac for myself friday evening

Comment: @Strom, i formed wront. Correct was that "will of help could evolve ONLY under EASY conditions!"

Comment: This chat is the proof. I've tired to force/how it to say/ rude to ask rude you to do this forcefully. And will of help is very artificial. If it would be real, that easy task would alredy have been solved. Do you understand that? That is no help, that's an illusion of Q/A site but its some politics not actual realtime solver, as it **COULD(SHOULD?) EFFECTIVELY BE!** (Translate first sentence: "will is very artificial and is dictated by.."